# Examples of infinite intersecting families.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

I'm trying to think of examples of intersecting families with infinite cardinality. (Recall an intersecting family, $\mathcal{A}$, is a collection of sets such that $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{A}, A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.)

I've come up with $\mathcal{A}=\{A \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}: \{1\}\in A\}$, which you could do for any singleton. I'm having trouble cooking up examples that are not of this form.

If there was a maximum $n\in \mathbb{N}$ I could make, $\mathcal{A}=\{A \in 2^{[n]}: |A|>\frac{n}{2}\}$, except the natural numbers are unbounded to certainly that does not work either.

Comment: ${\cal A}=\{(-s,s)\subset\Bbb R:\, s>0\}$.

Comment: That's certainly one! Hoping to restrict my focus to natural numbers though.

Comment: ${\cal A}=\{\{1,\cdots,n\}:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$

Comment: Let $\mathscr{A}=\{\Bbb N\setminus F:F\text{ is a finite subset of }\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: Also building on @TitoEliatron 's result the image of those intervals under any function where the image of the real line has infinite cardinality. Which should let you make many examples which meet your restrictions. A={$f(-s,s):(-s,s)\subset R$ and $s>0$} The graphs of such functions also work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you had an $A = \mathbb{N} \backslash F_{1}$ and $B= \mathbb{N} \backslash F_{2}$ where $|F_{1}|,|F_{2}|<\infty$, so $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$. If $F_{1}\neq F_{2}$ why would $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$? .... Is it because then there is some $x$ such that $x \notin F_{1}$ and $x\notin F_{2}$, so then $x\in \mathbb{N}\backslash F_{1}$ and $x\in \mathbb{N}\backslash F_{2}$?

Comment: @GraphMathTutor: $$A\cap B=(\Bbb N)\setminus F_1)\cap(\Bbb N\setminus F_2)=\Bbb N\setminus(F_1\cup F_2)$$ by De Morgan’s law, and $F_1\cup F_2$ is finite.

Comment: The generalization of $\{A\subseteq [n]:|A|>n/2\}$ to subsets of $\mathbb N$ would be any [non-principal ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilters_on_sets).